# How to hide 'prev' button on owl carousel if the first item is active?

Tags: html, css

1. How to hide 'prev' button on owl carousel if the first item is active?
   Or if the last item is active, hide the 'next' button (if carousel loop is false of course)

I've tried something like this but is not working because the 'owl-prev' and the buttons are not in the div 'mydiv'

```
.owl-item:first-child.active .owl-prev {
  display: none;
 }

 .owl-item:last-child.active .owl-next {
    display: none;
}
```

2. When click prev or next, to show the next 5 items, not just 1?

I have a code like this:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {


    var owl = $('.mydiv').owlCarousel({
        items: 3,
        dots: false,
        nav: true,
        loop: false,
        autoplay: false,
        autoplayHoverPause: true,
        mouseDrag: false,
    });
    


})
```

```css
.owl-prev, .owl-next {
  font-size: 65px !important;
}

.owl-next {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css?">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" integrity="sha512-tS3S5qG0BlhnQROyJXvNjeEM4UpMXHrQfTGmbQ1gKmelCxlSEBUaxhRBj/EFTzpbP4RVSrpEikbmdJobCvhE3g==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <body>
        <div class="mydiv owl-carousel">
            <div class="div-image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="div-image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="div-image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="div-image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="div-image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="div-image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="div-image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="div-image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt=""></div>
        </div>
        

        <!-- JQUERY -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <!-- OWL CAROUSEL -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js" integrity="sha512-bPs7Ae6pVvhOSiIcyUClR7/q2OAsRiovw4vAkX+zJbw3ShAeeqezq50RIIcIURq7Oa20rW2n2q+fyXBNcU9lrw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.disabled` class is already there you need to do CSS only

```
 button.disabled {
   opacity: 0.2;
   cursor: default !important;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(() => {


    var owl = $('.mydiv').owlCarousel({
        items: 3,
        dots: false,
        nav: true,
        loop: false,
        autoplay: false,
        autoplayHoverPause: true,
        mouseDrag: false,
    });
    


})
```

```css
     button.disabled {
       opacity: 0.2;
       cursor: default !important;
}
.owl-prev, .owl-next {
  font-size: 65px !important;
}

.owl-next {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css?">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" integrity="sha512-tS3S5qG0BlhnQROyJXvNjeEM4UpMXHrQfTGmbQ1gKmelCxlSEBUaxhRBj/EFTzpbP4RVSrpEikbmdJobCvhE3g==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <body>
        <div class="mydiv owl-carousel">
            <div class="div-image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="div-image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="div-image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="div-image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="div-image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="div-image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="div-image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="div-image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt=""></div>
        </div>
        

        <!-- JQUERY -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <!-- OWL CAROUSEL -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js" integrity="sha512-bPs7Ae6pVvhOSiIcyUClR7/q2OAsRiovw4vAkX+zJbw3ShAeeqezq50RIIcIURq7Oa20rW2n2q+fyXBNcU9lrw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

In *OwlCarousel* plugin there is already `.disabled` class on `first` and `last` slide. So you can `hide/show/transparent/opacity` as need by *CSS property*.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  var owl = $('.mydiv').owlCarousel({
    items: 3,
    dots: false,
    nav: true,
    loop: false,
    autoplay: false,
    margin: 10,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    mouseDrag: false,
  });
})
```

```css
.mydiv .owl-nav{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 0 10px;
    pointer-events: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.mydiv .owl-nav .owl-prev,
.mydiv .owl-nav .owl-next {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0 !important;
    font-family: Arial !important;
    font-size: 22px !important;
    line-height: 1 !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85) !important;
    pointer-events: all;
}
.mydiv .owl-nav .owl-prev.disabled,
.mydiv .owl-nav .owl-next.disabled{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="mydiv owl-carousel">
    <div class="div-image"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z12tw.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="div-image"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z12tw.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="div-image"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z12tw.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="div-image"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z12tw.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="div-image"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z12tw.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="div-image"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z12tw.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="div-image"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z12tw.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="div-image"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z12tw.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Aman's answer and solving the second part of your question, you can use `slideBy` option and specify the number to slide the carousel by a particular value.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {


    var owl = $('.mydiv').owlCarousel({
        items: 3,
        dots: false,
        nav: true,
        loop: false,
        autoplay: false,
        autoplayHoverPause: true,
        mouseDrag: false,
        slideBy: 5
    });
    


})
```

```css
.owl-prev, .owl-next {
  font-size: 65px !important;
}

.owl-next {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.owl-next.disabled, .owl-prev.disabled {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css?">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" integrity="sha512-tS3S5qG0BlhnQROyJXvNjeEM4UpMXHrQfTGmbQ1gKmelCxlSEBUaxhRBj/EFTzpbP4RVSrpEikbmdJobCvhE3g==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <body>
        <div class="mydiv owl-carousel">
            <div class="div-image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="div-image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="div-image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="div-image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="div-image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="div-image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="div-image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="div-image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt=""></div>
        </div>
        

        <!-- JQUERY -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <!-- OWL CAROUSEL -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js" integrity="sha512-bPs7Ae6pVvhOSiIcyUClR7/q2OAsRiovw4vAkX+zJbw3ShAeeqezq50RIIcIURq7Oa20rW2n2q+fyXBNcU9lrw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```